# How to marked checkbox in function jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, listbox

I have a listbox in view.

This Listbox use template

**Listbox**

```
<div id="UsersLoad" style="width: 50%">
    @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Users, "UsersForEdit") 
</div>
```

**Template UserForEdit** (Part of the code)

```
@model string[]
@{        
    if (this.Model != null && this.Model.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach(var item in this.Model)
        {
            listValues.Add(new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Value = item, Text = item });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listValues = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }    
}

<div class="field-@size @css">
    <h3>@Html.LabelFor(model => model):</h3>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model, listValues, new { id = id })
</div>
```

In another view div "Users" is called.

```
function LoadUsersCheckBox() {
    $("#UsersLoad").load('@Url.Action("LoadUsers", "User")' + '?idUser=' + idUser);
}
```

**LoadUsers Controller**

```
public JsonResult LoadUsers(int? idUser)
{
    var users =  Service.GetSystemUsers(idUser);
    var model = users.Select(x => new
                {
                    Value = x,
                    Description = x
                });

    return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The controller method returns what I want.

But instead of it select the items in the listbox it overwrites the listbox with only the text of found users.

How to mark the items in the listbox on the function `LoadUsersCheckBox`?

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery `load()` method "loads data from the server and places the returned HTML into the matched element." Note the words "the returned HTML". See http://api.jquery.com/load/

To select existing items, you should try `get()` instead (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/). In the success callback handler, you will need to parse the returned data to an array. Then use an iterator to go over the items in the listbox, and if they exist in the parsed array, mark them as selected. Something like:

```
$.get("action url", function(data) { 
    var users = $.parseJSON(data);

    $("#UsersLoad option").each(function() {
        var opt = $(this),
            value = opt.attr("value");

        opt.removeAttr("selected");    

        if (users.indexOf(value) > -1) {
            opt.attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The `action url` I can pass the action as follows: `@Url.Action("LoadUsers", "User")' + '?idUser=' + idUser` ?

Comment: Yes, because that just renders a string - the url

Comment: i have this error `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data` .

Comment: Please post a sample of your JSON data if you need assistance, though this is probably another question altogether. Anyhow, if you look at your LoadUsers action method, should probably rather be `users.ToArray()`. Why return an array of objects where value and description both equal x? This will also make it harder to match on the UI.